# Normalize groupby individually

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know the percentage of how much a player has won and lost by the total games he has played. The columns analyzed will be:

```
game | player | games
 aXa |  Jose  | has won
 aXb |  John  | has won
 aXb |  John  | has won
 uXu |  Adam  | lost
 bXb |  John  | lost
 oXo |  John  | lost
 pXp |  Jose  | has won
```

The output would look like this:

```
player | games | wins | losses
  John |   4   |  50% | 50%
  Jose |   2   | 100% | 0%
  Adam |   1   |   0% | 100%
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for counter and `join` with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) table:

```
df2 = (df['player'].value_counts().rename_axis('player').to_frame('games')
                   .join(pd.crosstab(df['player'], df['games'], normalize=0).mul(100))
                   .reset_index())

print (df2)
  player  games  has won   lost
0   John      4     50.0   50.0
1   Jose      2    100.0    0.0
2   Adam      1      0.0  100.0
```

Comment: Sensational! I was trying to separate wins and losses and then normalize, but the way you did it looks great. Thank you!

Comment: I did not understand normalize = 0, could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution using `apply` on grouped dataframe:

```
df_out = df.groupby('player')   \
           .apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'games': len(x.game),
                                       'wins': 100*sum(x.games == 'has won')/ len(x.game),
                                       'losses': 100*sum(x.games == 'lost')/ len(x.game)})) \
           .reset_index()

print(df_out)
   player  games   wins  losses
0  Adam      1.0    0.0   100.0
1  John      4.0   50.0    50.0
2  Jose      2.0  100.0     0.0
```